# Query a dynamic-key nested dictionary structure in Cosmos DB with LINQ to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, linq-to-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I want to query for values in a *dynamic-key* nested dictionary structure in order to apply a permission filter using LINQ to SQL (preferably utilizing index queries and not causing scans).

The JSON structure I have contains a `Permissions` property which is basically just a C# `dictionary<string, dictionary<string, dictionary<string, string>>>`

**JSON example:**

```json
{
    "Permissions": {
        "Account 1 GUID": {
            "Location": "Location1 GUID"
        },
        "Account 2 GUID: {
            "Location": "Location 2 GUID"
        },
        "Account 3 GUID": {
            "Location": "Location 3 GUID"
        }
    }
}
```

The account key properties are dynamic, meaning they are in fact the GUIDs of the accounts owning the nested location.

When a query is performed I have a list of location and account IDs that should be used to perform the permission filtering by giving access only to those locations.

The filtering query I want to apply is **SIMILAR TO SOMETHING** like this (**THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**):

```cs
var allowedLocations = new List<string> { "Location 1 GUID", "Location 2 GUID" };

var result = AllDocsIQueryable.Where(model => 
    model.Permissions.Values.Where(secondLevel =>
        secondLevel.Values.Where(thirdLevel =>
            allowedLocations.Contains(thirdLevel)))).ToList();
```

As you can see, I want to filter the docs a user can see to those the user has defined an access to, by querying for docs that contains any of the location IDs in my access list.

I have no idea how to go about construction the query for querying a structure like this. I have tried many combinations of `.Select` and `.SelectMany` queries, but nothing I have tried succeeds, all I have tried yields no results or fails.

A query *like* the following yields the correct results, but I would really like to avoid having to build this query dynamically with predicate builder for example:

```cs
var result = AllDocsIQueryable.Where(model => 
    (model.Permissions["Account 1 GUID"]["Location"].IsDefined() &&
    model.Permissions["Account 1 GUID"]["Location"] == "Location 1 GUID")
    ||
    (model.Permissions["Account 2 GUID"]["Location"].IsDefined() &&
    model.Permissions["Account 2 GUID"]["Location"] == "Location 2 GUID")
    // .. etc ..
    ).ToList();
```

I hope my question is clear and there is a LINQ to SQL/Cosmos/NoSQL/C# super wiz that can help me construct this query? Maybe someone knows that I can't construct this query at all, and I need to change the JSON structure (which I know would be preferable)? I need to query using LINQ and not SQL query string!

**Conclusion:**

It seems, as I was afraid of, that there's just no way of building the query.

As far as I know, and have tried, and read, there's just no way to do it without building the dynamic account keys into the query.

I've changed the schema to include arrays instead.

```json
"Permissions": [
    {
        "LocationId": "Loc1",
        "AccountId": "Acc1"
    },
    {
        "LocationId": "Loc2",
        "AccountId": "Acc2"            
    }
]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The LINQ query you provided doesn't even compile, so why are you claiming it doesn't yield any results? Why are you checking "Location 1 GUID" only against "Account 1 GUID" and "Location 2 GUID" only against "Account 2 GUID"? Please make it completely precise what you are trying to achieve. Also, please clarify if you must use LINQ or whether you may also construct an SQL query string.

Comment: @MoB. I have edited and tried to clarify the question a bit. **1)** _The filtering query I want to apply is SIMILAR TO SOMETHING like this:_ **2)** _I need to query using LINQ and not SQL query string!_ **3)** I know what account ID the location ID is in. I don't understand your question regarding this? I would like to just filter by any location hits from the allowed list as you can see in the example query I would _LIKE_ to be able to use! I think I'm actually pretty precise in what I'm trying to achieve, but I have made a bold note on what it is I need!

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear. Your LINQ query doesn't make any sense. So basically you ignore the account ID and just want to check if any of a given set of location IDs is contained in the permission object of the document?

Comment: Can you change the document structure? Then you could store the account ID in a property "accountId", and the permissions would be an array and the query would be very simple.

Comment: @MoB. Yes, exactly! That is what I want to achieve! In the second query I illustrate how using the Account ID GUIDs, I can achieve a query yielding the correct results. BUT, I note that I don't want to do it like that, as I need to build that (quite large) query dynamically, right?

Comment: @MoB. I know changing the structure would be optimal, but not what I can/want to do. I either need the query or a statement telling me definitively "NO CAN DO". I cannot contruct the query that allows me to "query past" the account ID keys, and just make a Contains query on the Location ID in my allowed list, which is very much what would be preferred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way you can achieve that just using LINQ. Here are your options:

- Use a UDF to retrieve an array of locations from a permissions object. Unfortunately, you can't call a UDF from LINQ (at least not in SDK v3 - you *can* in SDK v2), so you need to use raw SQL. (Actually there is hacky way.) This solution is bad because it's really slow.
- Leave your schema but introduce an additional property that contains a list of locations that occur nested within your permissions object. Now you can easily use LINQ, and the query is fast.

Comment: Yeah! UDF isn't the route I want to take either!

As far as I know, and have tried, and read, there's just no way to do it without building the dynamic account keys into the query - which is what I already have and works.

I've already changed the schema to include arrays instead and just have to bite the apple and do a full migration...